# Find in ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a page where I can either display *all* customers' details, or if specified in the params, just *one* customer's details.

My controller looks something like this.

```
def display_customers
  @all_customers = Customer.all
  if params[:customer_id]
    @customers = Customer.find(:all, conditions: ["id = ?", params[:customer_id]])
  else
    @customers = @all_customers
  end
end
```

I use `@all_customers` to populate a dropdown of customers.
I use `@customers` to perform an `each` loop through each customer.
Then, if the `customer_id` param is specified, `@customers` will just be the single customer.

This works just fine but `@customers = Customer.find(...)` is an extra DB query.
I already have all the customers in `@all_customers` so I though there would be a better way to grab the one record I need from there - instead of going back to the DB again.

Comment: You should really, *really* start using two spaces per level of indent. It's not acceptable within the Ruby community to make up your own indentation style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) which is built in to all Enumerables...

```
if params[:customer_id]
  @customer = @all_customers.find { |c| c.id == params[:customer_id] }
else
  #...
```

... but probably shouldn't.

Depending on the number of records, this may not be any faster, as your database query will use an index, where the above code uses a linear search through all the returned records. Chances are a second database query is the way to go.

You should also rewrite your query. Rails is smart enough that you don't have to pass conditions when finding a record by its ID; you just *find* it. These are identical:

```
# BAD:
@customers = Customer.find(:all, conditions: ["id = ?", params[:customer_id]])

# BETTER:
@customers = Customer.find_by_id(params[:customer_id])

# BEST:
@customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
```

If you really want it to be an array, just wrap the result in `[]`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was under the impression that cutting down queries was the way to go. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
def display_customers
  @all_customers = []
  if params[:customer_id].empty?
    @all_customers = Customer.all
  else 
    @all_customers << Customer.find(params[customer_id])
  end
  @all_customers
end
```

this way

your "`select * from customers`" query will only be executed when there is no `customer_id` param (not always). I believe its more efficient rather than selecting all from DB and then filtering

Comment: I need to get them all anyway, because I'm creating a <select> with all customers.